# Matching same characters in a row using regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to match "three uppercase letters, one lowercase letters, and three uppercase letters" using regular expression. What makes this difficult is that **adjacent uppercase letters must be same**. For example, I expect `AAAbCCC`, but not `AAAbCCD` or `ABAbCDC`.

Here is what I've tried:

```
print(re.findall("[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}", l))
```

However, this is not what I want, because it matches `AAAbCCD` and `ABAbCDC` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use capture groups and backreferences:

```
re.findall(r"(([A-Z])\2\2[a-z]([A-Z])\3\3)", string)
```

Note, however, that in the presence of groups in the pattern [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.findall) will return the groups instead of matches.
So to get the matched strings you'll need to enclose the whole pattern in parentheses and take the 1st group:

```
>>> s = "AAAbCCC AAAbCCD"
>>> [groups[0] for groups in re.findall(r"(([A-Z])\2\2[a-z]([A-Z])\3\3)", s)]
['AAAbCCC']
```

You can also use [`re.finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.finditer), which returns an iterator over the *match objects*:

```
>>> [match.group(1) for match in re.finditer(r"(([A-Z])\2\2[a-z]([A-Z])\3\3)", s)]
['AAAbCCC']
```

Answer (score 3):

Leverage captured grouping:

```
^([A-Z])\1\1[a-z]([A-Z])\2\2$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8b4yuL/4)

- `^([A-Z])` captures the first uppercase, and put in captured group 1, `\1\1` matches next two characters if they are same as the captured one. same goes for the second captured one, later referenced by `\2`

You can use range matching, `{}`:

```
^([A-Z])\1{2}[a-z]([A-Z])\2{2}$
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `([A-Z])\1{2}[a-z]([A-Z])\2{2}`.

It stores the first found upercase character in a group and reuse it with `\1` (and `\2`) to check the two following chars.